# Decidable equality statement with Set vs. Prop

Tags: coq

When looking at results for types with decidable equality (especially in [Eqdep_dec](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html)) there are some of the results that (for a type `A`) require

```
  forall x y : A, x = y \/ x <> y
```

whereas some require

```
  forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}
```

It is my impression that it is the last one that is referred to as *decidable equality*, but I am very much uncertain what the difference is.  I know that `x = y \/ x <> y` in `Prop` and `{x = y} + {x <> y}` is in `Set`, and I can prove the first one from the second one but not the other way around.  As far as I understand it, it is because I am not allowed to construct values of type `Prop` from values of type `Set`.

Can anyone tell what the difference between the two are? Are there some example of a type for which the first statement can be proved but not the second.  Also, is it true that the version with `{x = y} + {x <> y}` is what is referred to as decidable equality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the latter definition, the one which lives in `Set`, is referred to as *decidable equality*.

Intuitively, we interpret objects in `Set` as programs, and objects in `Prop` as proofs. So the decidable equality type is the type of a function which takes any two elements of some type `A` and decides whether they are equal or unequal.

The other statement is slightly weaker. It describes the proposition that any two elements of `A` are either equal of unequal. Notably, we would not be able to inspect *which* outcome is the case for specific values of `x` and `y`, at least outside of case analysis within a proof. This is the result of the `Prop` elimination restriction that you alluded to (although you got it backwards: one is not allowed to construct values of sort `Set`/`Type` by eliminating/matching on an element of sort `Prop`).

Without adding axioms, the `Prop` universe is constructive, so I believe that there would not be any types `A` such that equality is undecidable but the propositional variant is provable. However, consider the scenario in which we make the `Prop` universe classical by adding the following axiom:

```
Axiom classic : forall P, P \/ ~P
```

This would make the propositional variant trivially provable for any type `A`, while the decidable equality may not be realizable.

Note that our axiom is a proposition. Intuitively, it makes sense that either a proposition or its negation must hold. If we hadn't made this a `Prop` (for example, if we axiomatized `forall P, {P} + {~P}`), then we would likely not accept the axiom, since it would instead be declaring the existence of a universal decision procedure.

That was a bit of a digression, but hopefully it demonstrated some differences in our interpretation of `Prop`s and `Set`s.

Comment: Of course, that makes a tremendous amount of sense. This was exactly what I was looking for. Great example. Thanks :)